# How do I make Subject emit multiple times

Tags: angular, rxjs

It's the first time I try to get the sockets to work.

I base my socket service on this [tutorial](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-websockets-tutorial/).

Basically the whole thing boils down to a couple of services - `WebsockService` and `DashSocketService`.

Below is the code for both of them:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class WebsockService {

  constructor() {}
  private ws: WebSocket;

  private subject: Subject<MessageEvent>;

  public connect(url): Observable<MessageEvent>
  {
    if (this.subject)
    {
      this.ws.close();
    }
    this.subject = this.create(url);
    console.log('Successfully connected to: ' + url);
    return this.subject.asObservable()
  }

  public create(url): Subject<MessageEvent> 
  {
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);

    let observable = Observable.create(
      (obs: Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
        this.ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
        this.ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
        this.ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);

        return this.ws.close.bind(this.ws);
      }
    );

    let observer = {
      next: (data: Object) => {
        if (this.ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN)
        {
          this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      }
    };
    return Subject.create(observer, observable);
  }
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class DashSocketService {

  constructor( private wsService: WebsockService, private globals: Globals)
  {

  }

  public getDashInfoBySocket(filter_hash: string): Observable<Dash>
  {
    return this.wsService.connect(`${this.globals.WS_URL}/ws/channel/${filter_hash}`).pipe(
      map(
        res => {
          return new Dash().deserialize(JSON.parse(res.data));
        }
      )
    )
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if the code is written properly but the problem with this is that, as far as I understand, I can subscribe to this Observable only once. That's, if later I get `dash` (which is of type `Observable`), I can use it in the `dash | async` way only once, other attempts will return nothing.

So I would like to know how to make it possible to use this subject.asObservable() like a normal observable.

Comment: May I recommend using the RxJS creation operator for a WebSocket, instead of manually using a Subject? Creation operators should always be favored over other ways, unless you have a good reason why this is not sufficient. 

I am aware this is not an answer to your actual question, but just wanted to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code that subscribes, I can't be sure if this is the problem, but I'm going to go out on a limb and assume it is...

The issue is not so much how many times you can subscribe, but when you subscribe. Everything seems to be a Subject, and I'm assuming the services are as well.... Therefore any subscriptions made will wait for the next update before receiving the value. Basically, all subscriptions must be made before you subscribe. If you need the subscribers to get the existing value, you need to filter the values through a BehaviorSubject. Create a new BehaviorSubject, then subscribe to your existing Observable, and every time a new value is received, push it into your behavior subject. Then, have your component subscribe to the BehaviorSubject (asObservable()).

Hope this helps!